# trouble with python version in jupyterlab

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

When I run `python -V` in jupyterlab terminal session, I have Python 3.7.6

When I run `!python -V` in jupyterlab that kernel name is Python3.11, I have Python 3.6.9

When I run `!python3.11 -V` in both session, I have Python 3.11.3

I think second part that kernel name is 'Python3.11' is just name is Python3.11 and version of python is 3.6.9
I want to change python version 3.11 everywhere.
I tried but it dosen't work

Thanks